# Unity changes committed via Github create empty scenes and corrupted files

Tags: git, github, unity-game-engine

We are working on this Unity project on several computers using Github. Recently, I cloned the project on a new computer (Mac Os). I didn't change any of the settings of the project. 'hidden meta files' is still the option picked, as it is on all our other computers.

I can access without any problems changes made by my colleagues.

But when I commit my changes, usually new scenes or new prefabs, they are corrupted for other teammates.

For example, they can open the scenes but they appear totally empty. There is nothing in the hierarchy of the scene.

Prefabs I changed cannot be read at all, their icon is even displayed as some sort of blank.

I got no error message from github, or even from Unity. It's as if there was simply no data contained in those files, even though they have the same size.

I use the same computer on another project also shared on github and we don't have this problem.

Anybody has a suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at `git log` to see what you're actually committing? Or `git status` to see if you have any untracked files?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your metadata files and Library folders. You may want to exclude them from being tracked. It's problematic when you clone from PC to PC, and include the metadata/Library files and folders. You have items specific to only your given environment, and it's imperative that you exclude then from being committed in GIT.

It takes some time to open projects since the metadata has to be recreated, however it'll mitigate corruption issues!